# Driver that determine is Shading of specific Viewport = 'RENDERED'

Tags: drivers

I want to make a driver, that will return `1` or `0` depends on is specific viewport shading type = `'RENDERED'`

Is that possible? So how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
import bpy

# two sample functions
def st():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            space = area.spaces.active
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                print(space.shading.type)
                if space.shading.type == 'MATERIAL':
                    return 1
                if space.shading.type == 'SOLID':
                    return 7   
            
    return -1





# Add functions defined in this script into the drivers namespace.
bpy.app.driver_namespace["st"] = st
```

Note: you have to extend the types by all types (i just added 2) and give the return value as you need it. In the driver use scripted expression and enter

```
st()
```